# Uipath try/catch problem - throwing system exception

Tags: try-catch, uipath

Having some trouble with try/catch in UiPath:

Got two different projects with their own workflows, with try catch implementations exactly the same in both.

However, one of the try/catch is working absolutely fine, whereas the other one is giving troubles with the following error when I Throw an exception, and then the steps defined in the catch block doesn't even trap it and execute.

Thoughts/Suggestions will be much appreciated - Thanks!

```
RemoteException wrapping System.Exception: <My user defined message>

   at System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)

   at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)

   at System.Activities.ActivityInstance.Execute(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)

   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
```

Comment: Hi Ash. It may be hard to help because of missing information. Please try to explain in more detail, what your workflow do. Regardless, here are some hints: Compare dependencies in both projects. (Are they really the same?) Compare inputs and every activity including they parameters. (There must be some "small hidden" difference easy to overlook, I guess.) Regards.

Answer (score 2):

If you have been using the **Try Catch** with the **general Exception**, it should be working in the same way in any project.

I believe you was a bit confused by the **running mode**.

So I assume in one project you fired the project in the **debug mode**. This stops on the exception when it occurs. If happening you need to hit the **continue button**.

But if you run the project with the **Run button**, it will **ignore** the **exception handling** as breakpoint and will continue now without any break.

So make sure in a live test you always run it with the run button and not with the usual debug button.